# How to check if the collection of data exists in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to add multiple names in database, before that i want to check if the name is already exists. database already has field `"Name": "radhaa"` but im getting this error `CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ Name: 'radhaa' }" (type Object) at path "Name" for model "user"` please help me thanks in advance

i'm trying with this below query.
`const roles = await User.find({ Name : req.body.Name })`

At the postman i'm trying like this:

```
[{
  "Name": "radhaa"
 },{
 "Name": "sitha"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an object `{ Name: 'radhaa' }` to the `Name` property in your model which is a `string`

seems the `req.body.Name = { Name: 'radhaa' }`
while it should be `req.body.Name = 'radha'`

double check the request body you sent from postman,

after all the `req.body` should be like this `{ Name: 'radha' }`

while it has been sent like this I guess `{ Name: { Name: 'radhaa' } }`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you first want to check whether the name already exists or not, you have to use `.find()` method and use `if..else` to check if the name already exist. If it exists then return the response and else if it doesn't exists, save the record to database.
2. As you are trying to send an array as the request body, you will have to use loop and for each value of array check use the `step 1` which I mentioned above, and this way you can get only unique values in your database.

**Note :** Please check the names of property and keys of your mongodb database. lowercase and uppercase matters.